# I integrated the grafana with azure ad but during login it was giving login failed bad request

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, grafana, microsoft-entra-id, azure-app-registration

I want to know why it was happening .I have added client id and secret auth and taken url everything needed for authentication I don't know why this happening.In the app registration also I have given the correct uri .given the enough permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps required to configure Grafana’s authentication with Azure AD.

1. Log in to Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com/), then click Azure Active Directory in the side menu.
2. Navigate to “Azure Active Directory” and select “App registrations.”
3. Click “New Registration” to create a new application registration.
4. Provide a name for the application, and select the appropriate redirect URI for Grafana like  [https://your-grafana-url/login/azuread](https://your-grafana-url/login/generic_oauth)  and  [https://your-grafana-url](https://your-grafana-url/login/generic_oauth).  Ensure the redirect URI in Azure AD exactly matches the URI configured in Grafana. Then click Register.
5. After registering the application, the app’s Overview page opens. Note down the “Application (client) ID” and the “Directory (tenant) ID.”

[image]

6. Under the “Certificates & secrets” section, generate a client secret, and make sure to note it down securely.

[image]

Upto here, above step remains same.

7. Here I will be using grafana via helmchart on an aks cluster, so with that approach add the helm chart for grafana accordingly

   helm init
   helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
   helm repo update

In the Grafana helm chart, we can set configuration values using the values.yaml file. Below is the sample configuration to add in values.yaml under grafana.ini section:

```
grafana.ini:  
auth.azuread:  
name:  Azure  AD  
enabled:  true  
allow_sign_up:  true  
auto_login  =  false  
client_id:  YOUR_CLIENT_ID  
client_secret:  YOUR_SECRET_ID  
scopes:  openid  email  profile  
auth_url:  
https://login.microsoftonline.com/AZURE_TENENT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize  
token_url:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/AZURE_TENENT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token  
allowed_groups:  GROUP_OBJECT_ID  
allowed_organizations:  TENANT_ID
```

These client id and secret you have already saved it from the above AD step. Add those here.

8. Install or upgrade Grafana using the helm chart

```
helm upgrade -install chart_name -f values.yaml
```

and your grafana is ready.

Second option-

If you are just setting up a standard [grafana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-grafana/quickstart-managed-grafana-cli) instance, and not deploying it on AKS goto azure portal-> Azure managed Grafana-> Create new and follow the steps provided in the MS doc link. Just ensure you have selected managed identity while setting up [grafana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-grafana/quickstart-managed-grafana-cli) via portal or cli.

[image]

Once ready you can access it via the provided endpoint
[image]
[image]

Reference:

[Managed Grafana on AKS](https://sigmoidanalytics.medium.com/grafana-authentication-with-azure-ad-and-okta-5642dff5ec25)
[MS Doc Managed Grafana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-grafana/quickstart-managed-grafana-portal)